# Mapping Enum value with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums

I want to map Enum's value with hibernate for fetching data from DB.
In DB column `**EASE_RATING** is number[1]`. I'm able to save data in DB as Numeric.

But When I retrieve data by Criteria.list() I get **easeRating=Two** instead of **easeRating=2**.

My  question is How can I get Data in form of Ordinal Or Enums's Value.

```
public enum Rating {

    Zero(0), // [No use] Taken Zero B'Coz Ordinal starts with 0
    One(1),
    ...
    Five(5);

    private final int value;

    Rating(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }

    public static Rating getRating(int x) {
        switch(x) {
            case 1: return One; ...
            case 5: return Five;
        }
        return One;
    }
}
```

**POJO:**

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
@Column(name = "EASE_RATING", nullable = false)
private Rating easeRating;
```

**UPDATE**

I want this value in int[ordinal()] in Hibernate List().
I'm hitting DB through hibernate.

```
List<CustomerFeedback> result = criteria.list();
```

I can achieve value throgh `**getValue()**`

```
System.out.println(Rating.Five.getValue()); // 5
System.out.println(Rating.Five);            // Five
System.out.println(Rating.Five.name());     // Five
```

But How would I get this in Hibernate list()

Comment: The property is of type Rating. So what you get is not "Two". It's the instance of Rating `Rating.Two`. You can call getValue() on this instance to get its value.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate is working fine. you question is about Enum.
toString() default implementation returns the name of the enum. The name is the literal of the enum: "One", "Two", etc...

If you want to obtain the ordinal of a enum stating with 1, you have to create a new method, sincel ordinal() is final:

```
    /**
     * One-starting index enumeration
     */
    public enum Rating {

        One, Two, Three, Four;

        public int position() {
            return ordinal() + 1;
        }

        public static Rating getRating(int x) {
            return Rating.values()[x - 1];
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Rating one = Rating.One;
            System.out.println("ToString() (name): " + one);
            System.out.println("Ordinal position stating in 1: " + one.position());
        }

    }
```

Answer to update 1:
Why don't just map Rating list to a value list?

```
    List<Rating> ratings = Arrays.asList(Rating.values());
    List<Integer> ints = ratings.stream()
            .mapToInt(Rating::position)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: UPDATE: I want this in Hibernate list()

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need raw database data; my recommendation is that you should always use `Rating` enum and take the ordinal/value from its instances in use cases where you need it.

However, one of the solutions to meet your requirements could be to map another entity to the same table with the following mapping:

```
@Column(name = "EASE_RATING", nullable = false)
private Integer easeRating;
```

Also include any other desired columns in this entity (columns which you use in this use case). Then use this entity in the query.